# Separate users and their value from a texfile

Tags: c#, loops

I'm making a little bot for a chat server, in the bot there is a little gaming system where users can use coins to gamble. I'm running the bot from my PC and use a text file to store my data. I separate my users from their coins with a ':' char. I've a method that takes an argument whether you want an array of users or an array of coins. I think this would make it easier later on to find values that comes with the user. But I'm only getting empty arrays.

I'm pretty sure it can be done in a much slicker way, but I'm pretty new to programming, especially c#. I've tried debugging but it just goes out the loop without going any further and it isn't throwing any exceptions either.

Here is my method.

```
 private string[] separateUsersFromCoins(string option)
    {
        string[] users = { };
        string[] coins = { };
        string[] temp;
        string[] result = { "I fucked up somewhere." };
        char[] userSeparater = { ':' };
        string rawData = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Derk\Documents\BottingDiscord\CringeBot\CringeBotConsole\Coin.txt");
        temp = rawData.Split(userSeparater);
        for (int i = 0; i <= temp.Length; i += 2)
        {
            users[i] = temp[i];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= temp.Length; i += 2)
        {
            coins[i] = temp[i];
        }
        if (option == "users" )
        {
            result = users;
        }
        else if(option == "coins")
        {
            result = coins;
        }
        else
        {
           return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What does debugging tell you?  Saying "it just goes out the loop without going any further" is not clear.  Stepping through with the debugger should tell you what is happening during the for loops, which part of your if/else block is getting executed, etc.  You could also help us out by providing the text from the text file (your input), and an example of what you expect as an output from that.

Comment: What does your data file actually look like? If it's structured in lines use `File.ReadAllLines` to read it in and then split each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your method, you can use following code:

```
    int count = 0;
    string[] users = { };
    string[] coins = { };
    string[] result = { "I fucked up somewhere." };
    char[] userSeparater = { ':' };
    string path = @"FILE_PATH_HERE";
    try 
    {
        if (File.Exists(path)) 
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
            {
                string[] temp = sr.ReadLine().split(userSeparater);
                users[count] = temp[0];
                coins[count] = temp[1]
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        return result;
    }
    if (option == "users" )
    {
        return users;
    }
    else if(option == "coins")
    {
        return coins;
    }
    else
    {
       return result;
    }
```

You will need to use "using System.IO;" directive at the beginning of your file to use that code.